# How do I write an array to .csv in Java?

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to write a piece of code in Java that generates an array of data, and I would like to write that data to a CSV file in one single column. However, I'm struggling with getting the correct output. My program generates the population in the array

> double[] wasp = new double[1000];

which is populated by one of several functions, for instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < wasp.length; i++) {
                double mu = -10 + Math.random()*20;
                double sigma = 0 + Math.random()*10;
                wasp[i] = nextGaussian(mu, sigma);
                description = "Normal";
                Param1 = Double.toString(mu);
                Param2 = Double.toString(sigma);
            }
```

and I use the following code to try to write the array to CSV:

```
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Havok\\Google Drive\\Skripsie\\R\\JavaOut.csv");
    
    for (int j = 0; j < wasp.length; j++) {
        writer.append((char) wasp[j]);
    writer.append(",");
    }
    writer.toString();    
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

However, when I open the CSV file, it looks "corrupt", as if the characters weren't encoded right or something. The data also fills up much more than one column in the file.

The output I expect is a CSV file that contains a single column of real values; for instance,

> 1.467354
>
> 0.812738
>
> 3.595733

and so on. However, what I'm getting is a column full of something like the following:

> ,,,,,ï¿¼,ï¿¶,ï¿¼,,,,,ï¿¹,ï¿¯,ï¿¿,,ï¿¾,,,,ï¿¿,,,   ,,ï¿·,,ï¿²,ï¿²,ï¿¼,ï¿·,,,,ï¿¹,,ï¿·,,ï¿¸,ï¿µ,,,,ï¿º,,ï¿¶,,,ï¿°,ï¿¸,,ï¿»,,ï¿¾,ï¿º,    ,,ï¿¿,,ï¿¾,,ï¿¯,,ï¿¼,ï¿º,ï¿µ,,ï¿»,,ï¿¬,,ï¿·,ï¿¸,ï¿¹,,,ï¿

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at the tutorials on Java's home site and tried to adapt other similar solutions on StackOverflow, but it seems like I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: what is the content of wasp array?

Comment: You don't have to use writer.toString(). The code seems to be okay. Can you show what you were expecting and what you got?

Comment: Also, please show us the definition of `wasp`

Comment: Cool, will edit with the definition and a sample of the output.

Comment: What is the type of a `wasp`? Why you need `(char) wasp[j]` casting? If you want to have a CSV file with single column you do not need ",", but you need a line ending. If you add "," it means you have two column and one of the column is empty. You also do not need toString() and flush() method calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply convert your double to string using `String.valueOf(double d)` method.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Havok\\Google Drive\\Skripsie\\R\\JavaOut.csv");

for (int j = 0; j < wasp.length; j++) {
    writer.append(String.valueOf(wasp[j]));
    writer.append("\n");
}
writer.close();
```

Alternatively you can use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)  to format your double as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks so much; this was the exact problem. I did initially cast to string, but made a separate mistake and changed it to char casting when fixing that problem, for some reason. Whatever the case, this solution works 100%.

Answer (score 1):

In CSV format each set of data is delimited by a new line (\n) and each column is delimited by a comma. Therefore your code should look like this if you want a single column of data.

```
for (int j = 0; j < wasp.length; j++) {
    writer.append((char) wasp[j]);
writer.append("\n");
}
```

Comment: That is not a problem, author is casting int to char, instead of doing int to string conversion

Comment: Well, it's one of two problems.  This addresses the "it's more than one column" problem, without touching on the "corrupt output" problem.

Comment: Its likely that the original poster is doing something else incorrectly, however given the current amount of information i can only solve one of his problems.